# is there a replacement for while loop for update of concurrentMap with scala TrieMap

Tags: java, scala, concurrency

In java I'm use to do following:

```
boolean done = false;
while(!done) {
    Long oldValue = map.putIfAbsent(key, 1L);
    if(oldValue != null) {
        done = map.replace(key, oldValue, oldValue + 1);
    } else {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

now i see that in scala I'm better off using `TrieMap` (if i insist on the mutable version) i don't really understand if there is a one shot operation already exists in this `TrieMap` which will do this while loop for me, if yes can you please show an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful with `TrieMap` (at least the mutable one), it's not actually thread safe. At a minimum, it inherits a non-thread-safe implementation of `getOrElseUpdate`. I did not check whether other methods (such as `putIfAbsent`) have the same problem, but one concurrency bug is bad enough!

**Addendum**

Rather than add another comment, I'll put the new information here...

`TrieMap.putIfAbsent` has a `TrieMap`-specific implementation *but* its value parameter is *not* a by-name parameter, so if the purpose of the cache is to avoid expensive computations, it fails again!

Comment: `putIfAbsent` and `replace` are atomic according to the API, so at least you can write the same code as in the java version.

Comment: The ScalaDocs simply say it's a concurrent and thread-safe class, but until `getOrElseUpdate` (at a minimum) is fixed, that is simply not true.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it's dangerous (to say the least) to have a class with public methods that you have to never call, despite them looking like (and often acting like) what you want. I'm inclined to believe them, though, when they say particular methods are atomic.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. The current implementation is in flagrant violation of its contract. I only know this 'cause I witnessed the failures empirically when I tried to use the mutable `TrieMap` as a cache in a concurrent system and saw multiple evaluations of the 2nd argument to `getOrElseUpdate` for a given key. It is broken! (It's also easy to see why by looking at the library code.)

Comment: It does appear `putIfAbsent` is thread-safe, since it has a TrieMap-specific implementation, unlike `getOrElseUpdate`.

Comment: Using `promise` and `putIfAbsent` seems be a way.

Comment: Per [SI-7943](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7943), `getOrElseUpdate` has been thread-safe since 2.11.6, which was released on 25/Feb/15.