# Functional value, mutable state and thread-safety

Tags: scala, thread-safety, dynamic-programming, memoization

[From there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257378/is-there-a-generic-way-to-memoize-in-scala?answertab=active#tab-top)

Trying to introduce [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) into the recursion algorithm.

```
case class Memo[A,B](f: A => B) extends (A => B) {
  private val cache = mutable.Map.empty[A, B]
  def apply(x: A) = cache getOrElseUpdate (x, f(x))
}

private val fib: Memo[Int, BigInt] = Memo {
  case 0 => 0
  case 1 => 1
  case n => fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) 
}

def foo(n: Int) = {
  fib(n)
}
```

Does it mean that if we use mutable state and functional value (defined by val.. well almost functional value) then it is not thread-safe?

(`val fib` - looks like global scoped mutable variable/object)

Comment: Here you can rescue thread safety by using a `var` holding an immutable `Map` that is replaced on each update and which must be marked `@volatile`. Alternatively, you can use the (somewhat) thread-safe, mutable `Map` type `TrieMap`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286823/is-there-a-replacement-for-while-loop-for-update-of-concurrentmap-with-scala-tri/21287424#21287424 for an important caveat.

Comment: Actually given multithreading doesn't help much when constructing memoization: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20462893/2073130, use memoization for DP in single-thread only. By that way, regular `mutable.Map` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say yes, there can be a problem if more threads are calling `foo` at the same time. Even though I was thinking that if you're only adding to the map and always the same value for a key, there is no guarantee that it must work. If implementation of `getOrElseUpdate` method of Map is for whatever reason stateful, it would not work. The contract of mutable Map is by definition not thread-safe.

If you can, add synchronization to your map and you're fine:

```
private val cache = new HashMap[A, B] with SynchronizedMap[A, B]
```

Comment: @DNA In the question there is only single instance of `Memo`. If you're trying to propose another solution, yes that's even better, but I tried to answer his question.

Comment: Yes, I'd thought that `fib` was a `def` not a `val`, so you are quite right.